# How old was Sarah when God first promised that she would bear a son for Abraham?

Tags: genesis

How old was Sarah when God first made the promise that she would bear a son for Abraham?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that she was 90 yrs old:

> **Genesis 17:17** (NWT)
>   At this Abraham fell facedown and began to laugh and to say in his heart: “Will a man 100 years old have a child born to him, and will Sarah, a woman 90 years old, give birth?”

Comment: When quoting other sources, begin a new paragraph (after a blank line) with a ">" character, and finish with another blank line, and don't forget to include the version of the Bible you have used.

Answer (score 0):

I heard that at the age of 90 sarah did give birth and in the torah this was called a miracle and when this happened abraham was 100 years old.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).